# how to insert auto increment value for trigger in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

This is the trigger from [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) -

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname           text NOT NULL,
    salary            integer
);

CREATE TABLE emp_audit(
    operation         char(1)   NOT NULL,
    stamp             timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid            text      NOT NULL,
    empname           text      NOT NULL,
    salary integer
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in emp_audit to reflect the operation performed on emp,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'D', now(), user, OLD.*;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'U', now(), user, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'I', now(), user, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_emp_audit();
```

Now I want to add one more column in the `emp_audit` table which is a primary key, say `emp_audit_id`-
so now what should come here in the above SELECT query so that it can take care of PRIMARY KEY `emp_audit_id` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not want to write out the field list on the `INSERT` statements (other readers: see comments below), you need to use a regular `integer` as `PRIMARY KEY` and a manually created sequence.

First alter the `emp_audit` table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE emp_audit ADD COLUMN emp_audit_id integer PRIMARY KEY
```

Create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_empaudit_pk;
```

In the `INSERT` statements, add the next value from the sequence:

```
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'D', now(), user, OLD.*, nextval(seq_empaudit_pk);
    RETURN OLD;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'U', now(), user, NEW.*, nextval(seq_empaudit_pk);
    RETURN NEW;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO emp_audit SELECT 'I', now(), user, NEW.*, nextval(seq_empaudit_pk);
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

Make sure to verify the order of the fields after you alter the table and list the fields in the `SELECT` query in exactly that order.

Comment: This didn't helped. I already tried this as well and found that it is not working for triggers.

Comment: The field list changed so the `INSERT` statements needed an actual field list instead of the implicit full list when omitted. See updated answer.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea because I have many columns and I need to list them all in the INSERT query. So I am thinking to avoid the primary key instead. But Is it recommended to add a primary key in the history table ?

Comment: I wouldn't say the idea is bad, you just don't like long statements. That aside, you can use a simple `integer` as `PRIMARY KEY` and manually create a sequence which you let emit a new value in the `SELECT` queries of the `INSERT` statements. In that case you are again using all fields of the audit table so you can omit the field list.

Comment: I wrote the fields list on the INSERT statements before your this recent update and it worked well. But now I am thinking that if I have to add any new column to the table in the near future then I have to do the changes in the SELECT queries of the trigger to add that extra column. Isn't it a extra overhead ?

Comment: I understand that this is obvious because you added the column in the original table so you do have to add that extra column in its history table as well together with in the INSERT statements.